# How to make a fixed navigation bar stretch to the width of the browser?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a fixed horizontal navigation that stretches to the browser's width.The problem I am having is that the links in the navigation bar move when i resize the browser window. How can I make it so that when you resize the web browser, the links(Home, Services...) stay fixed to the right and vertically in-line with the #content.?

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>        
<!--Navigation-->
<div id="fixed_bar">
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<!--Content-->
<div id="content">
<!--Content-->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:yellow;
    color:black;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:"Sans-Serif", Helvetica, Arial;
}

/*Navigation*/
#navigation {
   background-color:green;
   color:black;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:fixed;
  top:0;
  z-index:99;
}
#navigation ul {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#navigation ul li{
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    clear:right;
}
#navigation ul li a{
    background-color:inherit;
    color:black;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    line-height:40px;
    clear:both;
}

/*Content*/
#content {
    padding-top:50px;
    margin:auto;
    width:900px;
    color:black;
    background-color:white;
}
```

I have been trying to solve this for hours, help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply your actual `#navigation` CSS rules to your `#fixed_bar` div and give `#navigation` the same width of the content (900px), let the browser calculate the margins with automatic margins and align the text to the right, so the `ul` will be at the right of `#navigation` while you keep the background, etc in `#fixed_bar`.

See it here: http://jsbin.com/bibulewa/1

And this is the CSS I've modified:

```
#fixed_bar {
   background-color:green;
   color:black;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   z-index:99;
}

#navigation {
  width: 900px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set navigation styling:

```
left:0;
right:0;
```

Comment: it doesnt make any changes

Comment: well, there are a lot of issues with your code. What happens if the screen is below 900px? In any case, what you are looking for can be created if you use #navigation as a container, put a 900px element inside of it with float:left, text-align:right and put the navigation inside of it...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for

1. I gave the ul an absolute position and align to the right:2%.
2. A top margin of 5px.
3. Remove the float and display the list as inline-block

Here's a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rezasan/kE7LK/

```
/*Navigation*/
#navigation {
background-color:green;
color:black;
width:100%;
height:60px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:fixed;
top:0;
z-index:99;
}
#navigation ul {
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
right:2%;
display:inline-block;
margin:5px;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
width:60%;
text-align:right;
}
#navigation ul li{
padding:5px;
display:inline-block;
}
#navigation ul li a{

background-color:inherit;
color:black;
vertical-align:middle;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:15px;
font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;
letter-spacing:1px;
line-height:3px;
clear:both;
}
```